# SQL Select Command Causing Memory Exception On ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Obligatory "This runs fine on my machine but nobody elses"

I have inherited a web app that I am now trying to make one slight change to, but is causing users machines to hang when loading the app.

On the app a `SelectCommand` is called to concatenate some items from a database, and put them on the page.

The original 100% working command is:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT *, SetType + ISNULL(', startF: ' + STR(startFlevel), '') + ISNULL(', TOD: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), (SELECT MIN(createdTime) FROM PreviousEv WHERE setID=S.setID), 24), '') AS HeaderInfo FROM AllSet S INNER JOIN RNotes R ON R.setID=S.setID WHERE sesID=@sesID ORDER BY S.setID DESC">
```

I have made a tweak to this line where I join another table, and add another item to be concatenated into `HeaderInfo`

My edited line:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT *,S.SetType + ISNULL(', startF: ' + STR(startFlevel), '') + ISNULL(', TOD: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), (SELECT MIN(createdTime) FROM PreviousEv WHERE setID=S.setID), 24), '') + ISNULL(', Note: ' + setAppend,'') AS HeaderInfo FROM AllSet S INNER JOIN RNotes R ON R.setID=S.setID INNER JOIN Setups X on X.setID=S.setID ORDER BY S.setID DESC">
```

I am using VS2017 and on my end the project builds fine and the results on the web app are expected. However, on two other machines with VS2017 set up just like mine the app builds but does not load and seemingly pegs their memory. This is the only line in the code that has changed, and my intuition is telling me there is an issue with what I've written but I can't see it.

Edit: 
We are all able to query the database just fine with the above code.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What do you mean it does not load?  What do you mean it seemingly pegs their memory?  Your title indicates an exception--does it throw an exception?  If so, post the exception and stack trace.

Comment: @PhilSandler The web page will not load at all, and under task manager the memory goes up to 100%. I will try to recreate the exception.

Comment: @MaxB SSMS is not a DBMS. It's just a tool to use to interact with a particular DBMS. If someone asks you what DBMS you're using, you might say something like "Oracle 12c" or "SQL Server 2016".

Comment: @mason ah thank you. I've very much been dropped into the deep end and this is my first go at all of this stuff. It appears I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Second query is different is as it joins another table and has no WHERE clause - make sure it works against database (maybe it returns millions of records, who knows) and share table structure with sample data.